# How to combine to two bash variables (one including path and one including filename) inside the bash command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have an input directory (`INPUT_DIRECTORY=${PWD}/INPUT`) and a directory for output to save files into it a bash command (`OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${PWD}/Output`)
and a file  (`image-99.nii`) need to be written in the `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. I have saved the file name with its basename into two variables (`name=image-99.nii` and `FILENAME=image-99`)

```
for FILE in ${INPUT_DIRECTORY}/*.nii; do
    name="echo ${FILE##*/}"
    FILENAME=$(echo "$name" | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    ....
```

How to concat `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `FILENAME` in a way that the name becomes `"image-99-N4.nii"`. I did the following command, but did not work

```
OUTPUTNAME="${OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${FILENAME}_N4.nii"
```

When I `~$ $OUTPUTNAME` , I am getting an error `bash: /echo: No such file or directory`

Comment: You should add all relevant parts... we don't know from the question what is `$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: Sidenote: Avoid using uppercase variable names unless they're environment variables. See [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/4518341) for details. You haven't overwritten any environment variables here, but if you used `PATH`, for example, that could easily break a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the line with `OUTPUTNAME=`, which is correct.

```
name="echo ${FILE##*/}"
```

should be

```
name="${FILE##*/}"
```

otherwise, `echo` will be part of the filename which is obviously not what you want.

But anyways. `~$ $OUTPUTNAME` will only work, if the file is made executable. You might want `echo "$OUTPUTNAME"` or `ls ...`.